# gcc cross assembler problem

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I have bulit gcc cross compiler with 'powerpc-eabi' as TARGET in windows using cygwin.

When assembling the follwing code `lis r4, %hi(IMMR_OFFSET)`, I was getting the following

errors.

```
init/code/sfiles/init_core.s:141: Error: bad expression

init/code/sfiles/init_core.s:141: Error: syntax error; found `h', expected `,'

init/code/sfiles/init_core.s:141: Error: junk at end of line: `hi(IMMR_OFFSET)'
```

I would like to know why the above errors appear for every lis instruction similar to above.

Please help in this direction.

The value of IMMR_OFFSET is defined in another `.h file` as below....

```
.equ IMMR_OFFSET, 0xF0010000
```

I am using the follwing command for assembly....

```
c:/cygwin/home/cdot/powerpc/bin/powerpc-eabi-as -mbig-endian -g --defsym _NDI_=1

 --defsym _DBGR_ON_=1 --defsym DEBUG=1 --defsym _PARAM_DEBUG_=1 --defsym _NIU_=1

 -gdwarf-2 -I init/code/hfiles -o init/build/niu_ndi_dbgr_init_core.o init/code/
sfiles/init_core.s 2>init/build/niu_ndi_dbgr_init_core.err
```

Comment: I can't help you with the solution, but note that IMMR_OFFSET does not have anything to do with your problem. The compiler complains that after `lis r4, %` it would expect a comma ... in other words it doesn't understand what `%hi(...)` is supposed to mean in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that your assembly source is expecting to be built with a different assembler...

Some PPC assemblers do support the `%hi(foo)` syntax, but not the GNU assembler (unless there is some poorly documented option that I'm not aware of).

It also won't recognise `r4` as a register name unless you use the `-mregnames` flag.

The equivalent in the GNU assembler syntax is

```
lis 4, IMMR_OFFSET@h
```

(or `lis r4, IMMR_OFFSET@h` will also work if you use `-mregnames`).

Similarly, `%lo(foo)` and `%ha(foo)` would need to be written as `foo@l` and `foo@ha` respectively.